# Visual Studio Cannot Find CIODMLib Project Reference On Windows 7 64 Bit Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64, indexing-service

I am currently in the process of upgrading our developer environment to Windows 7 64 bit.

I have a C# project reference to CIODMLib which is a COM reference to "C:\windows\system32\ciodm.dll" on Windows XP. For some reason, that COM component does not exist on Windows 7 even though the dll is there. I've already verified that Indexing Services is enabled on my dev box, and I've already tried registering the C:\windows\system32\ciodm.dll using regsvr32, but it's still not showing up in the Add References "COM" dialog box.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just taking Interop.CIODMLib.dll from my XP machine and addint a reference to that. Seems to work on Win7. Not the best solution in the world, but at least I can move on to other Win7 x64 issues with the app.